# Is there a way to manually edit AsyncStorage in React-native (like LocalStorage in DevTools)?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

In web dev you can open up `DevTools > Application` and edit `Local Storage` manually.

[image]

Is there similar functionality in RN?

I've installed [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron), but doesn't have this functionality, it only displays what lives in `AsyncStorage`, no edits.

Comment: I don't know much about native code but, on iOS AsyncStorage handles with native code and in files. You can find the directory [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/50675404873c1ffac0deedc51fe745168051148b/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m#L19). In android its either SQLite or RoksDB. You can find those db files, open and edit them manually. But I don't think there is an easy way.